# Getting device twin in Swift Sdk - Azure IoT Hub

Tags: ios, swift, azure, azure-iot-hub

Is there a way to get the device twin of a device from Azure IoT-Hub, using `Azure SDK for Swift`?

As far as I know, I am able to get the device twin using the Azure SDK for NodeJS and also its possible for C and others.

In the documentation it says that the swift sdk is a part of the C sdk. But i didnt know how to get the device twin into swift. I tested with the given code example in the docs but its only how to send messages to the device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a way to get the device twin of a device from Azure IoT-Hub, using Azure SDK for Swift?

As per this open [issue](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/azure-iot-samples-ios/issues/19), as of now, there is no sample available for `IoTHubDeviceTwin_GetTwin` using Azure SDK for Swift.

Alternatively, as suggested by [Roman](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/628178/iosswift-display-azure-iot-hub-device-twin-reporte.html), you can get the device twin using [REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/iothub/service/devices/get-twin).

```
GET https://fully-qualified-iothubname.azure-devices.net/twins/{id}?api-version=2020-05-31-preview
```

For Swift, you can use [AsyncHttpClient 1.6.4](https://swiftpackageregistry.com/swift-server/async-http-client), [SAS token](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-dev-guide-sas?tabs=node) for authorization header and create it using [Device Explorer](https://github.com/fsautomata/azure-iot-sdks/blob/master/tools/DeviceExplorer/doc/how_to_use_device_explorer.md).